# Bootstrap Gem Installation Issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, github

I have added the bootstrap-sass gem and have installed the bundle. I have gone to github and think I have followed the directions correctly to finish the install for ruby on rails. It doesn't appear to be making a difference however on my local site - **no font/formatting changes have been made, even after the install.**

I am using a PC, https://github.com/findingtheway/pin

Answer (score 1):

Change your `app/views/layouts/application.html.erb` to this:

```
<head>   
  <title>Pin</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
```

Rails uses `application` by default you have `default` which is why bootstrap is not loading.